# MySQLdb python problem refresh database

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have wrote a python daemon for read a database... I do the next:

```
db.connect('localhost', user, pass, database)
while true:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT id FROM task WHERE status='pending'"
    r = cursor.execute(sql)
    if r != 0:
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        #.....
```

The problem is that: when change database, the daemon not detect it... can refresh...
what can I do??

thanks!!

Comment: Are changing the database during runtime?

Comment: yes I insert new tasks but it don´t detect them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have soluted it activating commit at the end of the script:

```
db.autocommit(True)
```

thanks for all friends

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess since I don't have a full view of your code, but since you're connecting outside the loop any changes to `database` won't tell `db` to reconnect.

Again just a guess, not sure if you're threading or not threading, how the change coincides with the daemon... etc

Comment: really it´s true, I only have one connection... because I want work with one connection...